# What is the best way to store temporary data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Here is my situation:

I am using Telerik controls and I would like the user to be able to add and delete information from a RadGrid (G2). This RadGrid G2 resides inside a popup window from another grid (G1), so I want to avoid writing information to the database until the user actually clicks submit on G1.

I was thinking that whenever the user makes changes to G2, that I would update a temporary data table and bind that to G2. I wasn't sure if this was the best approach, or if there was a more efficient way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the ids to be deleted on a hidden html input text element (make it `runat=server`). When the user clicks `Submit` you take the value of the hidden html element and delete the IDs present there.

Note: This is not by any means a secure way of doing this since the user can manipulate the value of the html element manually and you may end up deleting something unintended. You need to evaluate if this is a security risk or not for your scenario.

Comment: Security is a concern for my situation. I decided to go ahead with the DataTable. It seems to be working well. Thanks for the response.